# How can I determine which driver to re-install on my Nvidia Jetson TK1?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, proprietary-drivers

**Question:**

I would like to re-install the nvidia driver on a 32 bit ARM computer running Linux for Tegra (L4T), however I don't know what the correct version of this driver is, where to get it, or how to install it properly.

**Background:**

I am trying to connect to an NVidia Jetson TK1 (32 bit ARM computer) using remote desktop.  When I run startx in terminal freezes at Loading extension GLX.

I ran sha1sum -c /etc/nv_tegra_release and at first libglx.so checksum FAILED (maybe apt-get upgrade broke it or something), but I replaced it with the original and now it says OK.

/usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so: OK

Unfortunately, that did NOT solve the problem ....

The consensus (mainly drawn from people with the same issue but different hardware), is that next I should purge and re-install the appropriate nvidia-xyz driver matching my graphics card.

**Board:**

Tegra K1 SOC
NVIDIA Kepler GPU with 192 CUDA Cores
NVIDIA 4-Plus-1™ Quad-Core 
ARM® Cortex™-A15 CPU

**Linux Distribution:**
head -n 1 /etc/nv_tegra_release

R19 (release), REVISION: 2.0, GCID: 3896695, BOARD: ardbeg, EABI: hard, DATE: Fri Apr 18 23:10:46 UTC 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer here: https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/linux-tegra

And you can find whole required materials about Jetson here:
https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/downloads

http://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/dlc/l4t-Jetson-TK1-Driver-Package-R21-5

http://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/dlc/l4t-Jetson-TK1-Sample-Root-Filesystem-R21-5

Although I did not test remote desktop as you did,
my Jetson-TK1 has R21 (rev 5.0).

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ head -n 1 /etc/nv_tegra_release    
# R21 (release), REVISION: 5.0, GCID: 7273100, BOARD: ardbeg, EABI: hard, DATE: Wed Jun  8 04:19:09 UTC 2016
```